# Populate a JTable

Tags: java, swing, lambda, jtable

I've got a `JTable`, and I want to know if there's a better way to populate it, here's my code:

```
//Metodo para llenar un jtable con datos de la base
public static DefaultTableModel llenarTabla(JTable tabla,String Consulta,Object []datos){
    try (Connection conexion = pool.getConnection(clsConexion.espera)){//Tomamos una de las conexiones que hay en el pool
        resultado = null;//Inicializamos la vareiable resultado a nula
        modelo=null;
        if(conexion!=null){//Si pudimos obtener una de las conexiones ejecutamos proceso
            resultado = Consulta(Consulta, datos);//Hacemos la consulta de los datos de la base y los alojamos en un resultset
            metaData = resultado.getMetaData();//Obtenemos los valores de la cantidad de columnas y filas que hay
            columnas = metaData.getColumnCount();//Contamos las columnas
            // Datos de las casillas
           ArrayList<Object[]> informacion =new ArrayList<>();//Creamos el vectoe donde donde alojaremos la informacion
            while (resultado.next()) {//Recorremos el resultset para tomar los valores
                Object[] momento=new Object[columnas];//Creamos vector para guardar la informacion mientras se recorre
                for (int i = 1; i <= columnas; i++) {//Tomamos los valores que esten en la fila - i - y en la columna en la que estamos del ciclo while
                    momento[i-1] = resultado.getObject(i);  //Anadimos los datos al vector
                }
                informacion.add(momento);//Anadimos el los datos de vector a informacion cuando terminamos con una fila
            } modelo=(DefaultTableModel)tabla.getModel();//Tomamos el modelo de la tabla en la que deseamos mostrar los datos
            for (int i = 0; i <informacion.size(); i++) {//Recorremos la informacion
                modelo.addRow(informacion.get(i));//Anadimos la informacion que este en la posicion - i - del vector
            }
            return modelo;
        }else{WebOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error Nivel 2:\n Metodo: clsConexion/llenarTabla.\nError intentando conectar mediate una conexion del pool.","Conectando con la base de datos.",WebOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);return null;}
    } catch(SQLException ex){WebOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error Nivel 2.2:\n"+ex+"\n Metodo: clsConexion/llenarTabla.\nError Intentando crear modelo para la tabla","Informacion de la base de datos.",WebOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);return null;}
}
//Data Manipulation Language (DML) & (DCL)-> SELECT, CALL, LOCK TABLE, MERGE
public static ResultSet Consulta(String consulta, Object []datos){//Metodo para realizar una consulta a la base, capturamos la consulta y los datos
    try (Connection conexion = pool.getConnection(clsConexion.espera)){//Intentamos darle valor a la conexion
        resultado = null;//Inicializamos la variable
        sentenciaPreparada = null;
        if(conexion!=null){//Verificamos si la conexion tiene valor
            sentenciaPreparada = conexion.prepareStatement(consulta);//Preparamos la sentencia
            if(datos.length >=1 && datos[0]!="SELECTSINPARAMETROS"){//Verificamos si en la consulta se cargaran parametros
                for(int posicion =1; posicion<datos.length;posicion++){//Cliclo para a;adir los datos a la consulta que esta alojada en la sentencia
                    sentenciaPreparada.setObject(posicion, datos[posicion-1]);//A;adimos el dato en la posicion que le indicamos y el dato
                } 
            }resultado = sentenciaPreparada.executeQuery();//Ejecutamos la sentencia
        }else{WebOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error Nivel 2:\n Metodo: clsConexion/Consulta.\nError intentando conectar mediate una conexion del pool.","Conectando con la base de datos.",WebOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);}
    } catch (SQLException ex) {WebOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error Nivel 2.1:\n"+ex+"\n Metodo: clsConexion/Consulta.\nError Intentando hacer una conulta DML|DCL a la base.","Consulta a la base de datos.",WebOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);}
    finally{
        try {
            sentenciaPreparada.close();//Cerramos la sentencia
        }catch (SQLException ex) {WebOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error Nivel 2.1:\n"+ex+"\n Metodo: clsConexion/Consulta DML|DCL.\nError Intentando cerrar sentencia.","Consulta a la base de datos.",WebOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);}
    }return resultado;
}
```

Also I would like to implement Lambda Expressions.

When populating a `JTable` what should i use, a `Vector` to store the data while reading it, or an `ArrayList`, what can i improve from the code?

And also if I want my `JTable` to dinamically add data for example if new data is inserted to the datebase, how can I make that the data that is inserted be showned without refresh the `JTable`, I mean, the `JTable` will be reading the data from the database constantly, but what do I have to change from the code above?

Comment: `"i'm a bit new, so please don't set this question off-topic, i just want to learn."` -- It might be closed for being too broad since what you've posted so far is a bunch of code and a vague wish to do it better and to lambdafy it. What specifically confuses you? What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i edit the question so, could you please answer it

Comment: `Hacemos la consulta de los datos de la base y los alojamos en un resultset`  Hmm.. comments in Spanish aren't much help on an English based forum.

Comment: @AndrewThompson sorry, i just copied the code, but you anyway i think you can understand the code

Comment: I don't look closely at code until it is compiled in my editor.  Even if the code is understandable, the comments are a waste of bandwidth.

Comment: @AndrewThompson ok, next time i won't add comments in spanish. Do you know how to do what i ask for in the last paragraph of the question ?

Comment: .. Does it not occur to you that if we wish to offer an answer, we'd already have *done that*?

Answer (score 1):

> when populating a jtable what should i use, a Vector to store the data while reading it, or an arraylist

The DefaultTableModel supports a Vector, not an ArrayList.

If you want to use an ArrayList then you need to use a custom TableModel.

Comment: but what's the difference between them?, which of them gives more advantages, i've read that Vectors contents is thread safe, but what does that mean?

Comment: Vectors are synchronized which adds extra overhead. People creating new apps will generally use an ArrayList. All updates to the TableModel should be done on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) which is thread safe so you can use an ArrayList or a Vector. The choice you have is to use an existing class, which practically speaking will not be a performance issue, or you must create your own TableModel which uses an ArrayList. I would first use the default classes to learn and understand how to use a JTable. Once you understand the strengths/weaknesses then you can create a custom model.